# How is input handled in Brainf***?

Tags: input, user-input, brainfuck

I can't really seem to find a standard for this. I know inputs are taken as ASCII values, but are they required to be single characters? If not, how are multi-character inputs handled?

Comment: The `,` command accepts one byte each time it runs. <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Commands> Maybe I don't understand the question, could you clarify?

Comment: @JoeSewell That is what I'm looking for, thanks! I looked at the esoteric wiki, but didn't think to check Wikipedia (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line inputs in most (if not all) programming languages are taken a line at a time. When you hit enter into a console after typing a line, the whole line gets sent into the program as a return value from the function you called to get the input.
In brainfuck, you have more control over this: You can get as many characters as you want at a time, and stop when you want to.
A single comma "," will get one byte's worth of input (a.k.a one character). If you want to handle getting a string until a newline is met, you can try implementing something like the following code (10 being the ascii value of newline and the number of repetitions of "+" and "-" chars):

```
[-]>,----------[++++++++++>,----------]<[<]
```

An array of non zero values starting and ending with zero values is saved into memory containing the ascii values of input chars.